# Expanding Dawson's integral in a series of Hermite functions

Tags: definite-integrals, hermite-polynomials

We want to show that
$$F(x)=\sqrt{\pi } \sum
   _{n=0}^{\infty }
   \frac{(-1)^n H_{2
   n+1}(x)}{2^{3 n+3} \Gamma
   \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}$$
where $F(x)$ is the Dawson Integral ($F(x)=\exp \left(-x^2\right)
   \int_0^x \exp
   \left(u^2\right) \, du$) and $H_n(x)$ is the $n$  th Hermite polynomial.

Since $F(x)$ is odd, we can write $F(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }
   c_{2 n+1} H_{2 n+1}(x).$ where
$$c_{2 n+1}=\frac{\int_{-\infty
   }^{\infty } \exp
   \left(-x^2\right) F(x) H_{2
   n+1}(x) \, dx}{2^{2 n+1} (2
   n+1)! \sqrt{\pi }}$$
Employing the generating function for the Hermite polynomials we can write
$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \exp
   \left(-(x-t)^2\right) F(x)
   \, dx=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }
   \frac{t^n \int_{-\infty
   }^{\infty } F(x) \exp
   \left(-x^2\right) H_n(x) \,
   dx}{n!}$$
How do we proceed to get the coefficient of $t^n$ ($n$ odd) on the left hand side ?

Comment: Which version of the Hermite polynomials do you have in mind? There are, unfortunately, two different common conventions (c.f. https://dlmf.nist.gov/18.3).

Comment: weight function is exp(-x^2). H_n NOT He_n

Answer (score 2):

We will proceed to evaluate the integral appearing above in $c_{2 n+1}$.
The Dawson Integral can be expressed in the form
$$F(x)=\int_0^{\infty } \exp
   \left(-y^2\right) \sin (2 x
   y) \, dy$$
Hence,
$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \exp
   \left(-x^2\right) F(x) H_{2
   n+1}(x) \,
   dx=\int_0^{\infty } \exp
   \left(-y^2\right)
   \int_{-\infty }^{\infty }
   \exp \left(-x^2\right) H_{2
   n+1}(x) \sin (2 x y) \, dx
   \, dy$$
To evaluate the $x$-integral on the right hand side we invoke the generating function for the Hermite polynomials.
$$\exp \left(-x^2\right) \sin (2
   y x) \exp \left(2 x
   t-t^2\right)=\sum
   _{n=0}^{\infty }
   \frac{H_n(x) t^n \exp
   \left(-x^2\right) \sin (2 y
   x)}{n!}$$
Integrating both sides with respect to $x$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ we obtain
$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \exp
   \left(-(x-t)^2\right) \sin
   (2 y x) \, dx=\sum
   _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{t^n
   \int_{-\infty }^{\infty }
   H_n(x) \exp
   \left(-x^2\right) \sin (2 y
   x) \, dx}{n!}$$
The integral on the left is readily evaluated as $\sqrt{\pi } \exp
   \left(-y^2\right) \sin (2 t
   x y)$. Expanding this expression in a power series in $t$ we obtain the realtion
$$\sqrt{\pi } \exp
   \left(-y^2\right) \sum
   _{n=0}^{\infty }
   \frac{(-1)^n (2 y t)^{2
   n+1}}{(2 n+1)!}=\sum
   _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{t^{2
   n+1} \int_{-\infty
   }^{\infty } H_{2 n+1}(x)
   \exp \left(-x^2\right) \sin
   (2 y x) \, dx}{(2 n+1)!}$$
where we have recognized that the integral vanishes for even values of $n$.
Equating coefficient of like powers of $t$ we have
$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } H_{2
   n+1}(x) \exp
   \left(-x^2\right) \sin (2 y
   x) \, dx=(-1)^n \sqrt{\pi }
   \exp \left(-y^2\right) (2
   y)^{2 n+1}$$
We then obtain
$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \exp
   \left(-x^2\right) F(x) H_{2
   n+1}(x) \, dx=(-1)^n
   \sqrt{\pi } 2^{2 n+1}
   \int_0^{\infty } \exp
   \left(-2 y^2\right) y^{2
   n+1} \, dy$$
The integral on the right hand side evaluates to $(-1)^n \sqrt{\pi } 2^{n-1} n!$
Finally, we find the desired coefficient
$$c_{2 n+1}=\frac{(-1)^n
   n!}{2^{n+2} (2 n+1)!}$$
which can be shown to be equivalent to that given in the original problem statement

Comment: This is nice.  There is a small typo I couldn't edit out b/c edits have to  be 6 characters...  In the sentence "The integral on the left is readily evaluated", the expression inline should not have $x$ in it -- subsequent expressions omit this and are correct.

Answer (score 1):

There is a shorter solution out there. First notice that Dawson's function can be expressed as

$$F(x) = -\frac{1}{2} i \sqrt{\pi}e^{-x^2} \text{erf}(i x) = x\,{_1}F{_1}(1,\frac{3}{2}, -x^2) \tag{1}$$
(from Olver et al. *NIST Handbook of Mathematical Functions*, 2010, 7.5.1 and 7.11.4)

in which ${_1}F{_1}$ is Kummer's confluent hypergeometric function.
Now there is a well-known expansion of Kummer's function in a series of Laguerre polynomials whose references you will find in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4852334/1114056), which straightforwardly leads to:

$$\begin{align}
&2x(1+t^2)^{-\gamma}\, {_1}F{_1} \left(\gamma, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{t^2}{1+t^2}x^2\right)      
\end{align} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\gamma)_n}{(2n+1)!}H_{2n+1}(x)t^{2n}  \tag{2},$$

where $(\gamma)_n=\gamma...(\gamma+n-1)$ is the ascending Pochammer symbol.

Choosing $\gamma = 1,\;t^2= - \frac{1}{2}$ and inserting into $(2)$ one finds (as $(1)_n = n!$):

$$ F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{n!}{2^{n+2} (2n+1)!}H_{2n+1}(x)  $$

which is already quite a nice result by itself. Now, by Legendre's duplication formula,

$$(2n+1)! = \Gamma(2(n+1)) = \frac{2^{2n+1}}{\sqrt{\pi}} n!\;\Gamma(n+\frac{3}{2}), $$

whence the formula to be proved follows straightforwardly.