# Correct Hermite polynomial generating function

Tags: generating-functions, hermite-polynomials

In the acclaimed encyclopedia of special functions by Ismail and Van Assche published in 2020 the following generating function is given for Hermite polynomials (p. 77, eq. (3.8.48)), without source:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\gamma)_n}{(2n+1)!}H_{2n+1}(x)t^n = \frac{x t}{\sqrt{1 + t^2}}\, {_1}F{_1} \left(\gamma, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{t^2}{1+t^2}x^2\right)$$

This published equation can easily be shown to be erroneous numerically. For instance, the first derivative of the RHS taken at $t=0$ is $x$, for all parameter values, while the first derivative of the LHS taken at $t=0$ is $\,2\gamma\,x (\frac{2}{3} x^2-1)$.

Question: Find the correct formula, ideally preserving the first two parameters of the confluent hypergeometric function $_{1}F_{1}$ in the RHS.

**Edit/Hint**

The correct formula is:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\gamma)_n}{(2n+1)!}H_{2n+1}(x)t^{2n} = 2x(1+t^2)^{-\gamma}\, {_1}F{_1} \left(\gamma, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{t^2}{1+t^2}x^2\right)$$

I have a tentative proof, which I will make into an answer within two weeks, hoping that the community will find a better one in the meantime.

---

**Reference**

Ismail, Mourad E. H. and Van Assche, W., *Encyclopedia of Special Functions: The Askey-Bateman Project, Volume I - Univariate Orthogonal Polynomials*, Cambridge University Press, 2020.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us start from the following generating function of the generalized Laguerre polynomials:

\begin{equation}
(1-u)^{-\gamma} {_1}F{_1}\left(\gamma, 1 + \alpha, \frac{ y\, u}{u-1}\right)  = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\gamma)_n}{(1+\alpha)_n} L_n^\alpha (y) u^n \tag{1}
\end{equation}

Equation $(1)$ was actually first published in 1937 by Erdelyi [1937, Eq. (5,7)] then  reestablished on independent grounds by F. Brafman [1951, p. 948, Eq. (28)], as a direct consequence of a general formula first obtained in 1943 by T.W. Chaundy [1943, p. 62], expanding generalized hypergeometric functions in series of associated polynomials.

Convergence conditions given in Erdelyi et al. [1953, Vol.~1, p.~276, 5.2 Eq.(6)] are: $|u| < 1, y > 0$, where $u$ may be complex by default. In Erdelyi's original publication, the condition on $y$ is more general, it is stated as $|\arg(y)| < \frac{3\pi}{4}$.

Setting:

$$\alpha = \frac{1}{2},\; y = x^2,\; u=-t^2 \quad \text{ with } \quad |t| < 1$$

in $(1)$, then recalling that Laguerre and Hermite polynomials are related by the well-known equation [NIST 2010, eq. 18.7.20, p. 445]:

$$H_{2n+1}(x) = (-1)^n 2^{2n+1}\, n! \, x\, L_{n}^{\frac{1}{2}}(x^2) $$

and noting that, by Legendre's duplication formula:

$$\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)_n 2^{2n+1}\, n! = \frac{2^{2n+2}\Gamma\left(n+ \frac{3}{2}\right) \Gamma(n+1)}{\sqrt{\pi}} = 2\,(2n+1)!$$

straightforwardly yield the corrected version of the posted generating function:

\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\gamma)_n}{(2n+1)!}H_{2n+1}(x)t^{2n} = 2x(1+t^2)^{-\gamma}\, {_1}F{_1} \left(\gamma, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{t^2}{1+t^2}x^2\right)      
\end{align}

which is valid for all $x$ real and $t$ possibly complex, $|t|<1$, hence in domains compatible with iterated derivation of the RHS with  respect to the real variable $t$ in the neighbourhood of zero for all real values of $x$.

(Edit)

The fact that $u=t^2$ can be complex (with $|u| < 1$) leads to a very short proof of [this posted expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3985942/1114056) of Dawson's function in a series of Hermite polynomials.

---

**References**

Brafman 1951, *Generating functions of Jacobi and related polynomials*, Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, 2(6), pp.  942-949, American Mathematical Society.

Chaundy 1943,  *An extension of hypergeometric functions (I)*, The Quarterly Journal of Mathematics,  os-14(1), pp. 55-78.

Erdélyi 1937, *Funktionalrelationen mit konfluenten hypergeometrischen Funktionen*, Mathematische Zeitschrift, 42(1), pp. 641-670

NIST 2010, *Handbook of Mathematical Functions Hardback and CD-ROM* Olver, F.W.J. and National Institute of Standards and Technology (U.S.) and Lozier, D.W. and Boisvert, R.F. and Clark, C.W.