# Correct another Hermite polynomial generating function

Tags: generating-functions, hermite-polynomials

This is a companion question to another one that I posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4844775) yesterday.

In the acclaimed encyclopedia of special functions by Ismail and Van Assche published in 2020 the following generating function is given for Hermite polynomials (p. 77, eq. (3.8.47)), without source:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\gamma)_n}{(2n)!}H_{2n}(x)t^n = (1+t^2)^{-\gamma}\, {_1}F{_1} \left(\gamma, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{t^2}{1+t^2}x^2\right)$$

This published equation can easily be shown to be erroneous numerically. For instance, the first derivative of the RHS taken at $t=0$ is uniformly $0$, for all parameter values, while the first derivative of the LHS taken at $t=0$ is $\,\gamma (2 x^2-1)$.

Question: Find the correct formula, ideally preserving the first two parameters of the confluent hypergeometric function $_{1}F_{1}$ in the RHS.

**Edit/Hint**

The correct formula is just the original one with even powers of the variable $t$ in the LHS expansion:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\gamma)_n}{(2n)!}H_{2n}(x)t^{2n} = (1+t^2)^{-\gamma}\, {_1}F{_1} \left(\gamma, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{t^2}{1+t^2}x^2\right)  $$

I have a tentative proof, which I will make into an answer within two weeks, hoping that the community will find a better one in the meantime.

---

**Reference**

Ismail, Mourad E. H. and Van Assche, W., *Encyclopedia of Special Functions: The Askey-Bateman Project, Volume I - Univariate Orthogonal Polynomials*, Cambridge University Press, 2020.

Comment: You should merge the two questions.

Comment: @Gary: well perhaps you are right. I was afraid it would result in a chunky bit that would be a bit heavy to tackle. I leave it to ME managers to decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the companion question, we start with the following generating function of the generalized Laguerre polynomials:

\begin{equation}
(1-u)^{-\gamma} {_1}F{_1}\left(\gamma, 1 + \alpha, \frac{ y\, u}{u-1}\right)  = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\gamma)_n}{(1+\alpha)_n} L_n^\alpha (y) u^n \tag{1}
\end{equation}

(see references in the companion question).
Convergence conditions are: $|u| < 1, y > 0$, where $u$ may be complex by default.

Setting:

$$\alpha = -\frac{1}{2},\; y = x^2,\; u=-t^2 \quad \text{ with } \quad |t| < 1$$

in $(1)$, then recalling that Laguerre and Hermite polynomials are related by the well-known equation [NIST 2010, eq. 18.7.19, p. 445]:

$$H_{2n}(x) = (-1)^n 2^{2n}\, n! \, L_{n}^{-\frac{1}{2}}(x^2) $$

and noting that, by Legendre's duplication formula:

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_n 2^{2n}\, n! = \frac{2^{2n}\Gamma\left(n+ \frac{1}{2}\right) \Gamma(n+1)}{\sqrt{\pi}} = (2n)!$$

straightforwardly yield the corrected version of the posted generating function:

\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\gamma)_n}{(2n)!}H_{2n}(x)t^{2n} = (1+t^2)^{-\gamma}\, {_1}F{_1} \left(\gamma, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{t^2}{1+t^2}x^2\right)      
\end{align}

which is valid for all $x$ real and $t$ possibly complex, $|t|<1$, hence in domains compatible with iterated derivation of the RHS with  respect to the real variable $t$ in the neighbourhood of zero for all real values of $x$.

---

**References**

NIST 2010, *Handbook of Mathematical Functions Hardback and CD-ROM* Olver, F.W.J. and National Institute of Standards and Technology (U.S.) and Lozier, D.W. and Boisvert, R.F. and Clark, C.W.